# Trigger.Once Spark Structured Streaming with KAFKA offsets and writing to KAFKA continues

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

- When using Spark Structured Streaming with `Trigger.Once` and processing KAFKA input

  - then if running the `Trigger.Once` invocation

    - and KAFKA is being written to as well simultaneously

      - will the `Trigger.Once` invocation see those newer KAFKA records being written during current invocation?
      - or will they not be seen until *next* invocation of `Trigger.Once`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manuals: it processes all. See below.

> Configuring incremental batch processing Apache Spark provides the
> .trigger(once=True) option to process all new data from the source
> directory as a single micro-batch. This trigger once pattern ignores
> all setting to control streaming input size, which can lead to massive
> spill or out-of-memory errors.
>
> Databricks supports trigger(availableNow=True) in Databricks Runtime
> 10.2 and above for Delta Lake and Auto Loader sources. This functionality combines the batch processing approach of trigger once
> with the ability to configure batch size, resulting in multiple
> parallelized batches that give greater control for right-sizing
> batches and the resultant files.